# How to change the Main IP of a dedicated Centos. cPanel Server?

Tags: cpanel, ddos

I have a cPanel server and it is using the main IP.

I got it from Online.net, now my main concern is how to change the IP of the server with a failover IP?

There is a DDoS attack on the main IP, and i want to turn it off completely and use a failover IP instead, all the DDoS attack on that IP, should be auto dropped as that ip won't be used.

How to do it?

Thank You.

PS: I have already started using Cloudflare, that's why i want to change the IP to prevent the DDoS.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just follow methods:

```
WHM => Basic cPanel & WHM Setup => Basic Config
```

Check below screenshot:

[image]

And finally Save changes.

To secure from DDOS use Use **CSF Firewall** and use **Comodo ModSecurity Apache Rule** to protect your websites from hackers

Comment: No, someone is DDOSing the IP directly, so it is affecting server. want to drop all the attacks on the server and add new Ip.

Comment: Use CSF Firewall and use Comodo ModSecurity Apache Rule

Comment: Will that work?

I was thinking to drop whole ip and put up a new one.